# exim filter not working on long emails

Tags: email, email-server, exim, filter, cpanel

I was trying to set a file extension based filter in exim.

```
if 
$message_body contains "pdf.gz"
or $message_body contains "pdf.arj"
```

This filter does work on small mail, such as mail with only test data and one spam attachment like test.pdf.gz

but when it comes to actual scenario, when a mail with much data (This spam mail generally contains a legitimate company name and images some ivoices and attachments like gz and arj archives.) and it doesnt blocks it!

Is there any email size limit for filtering? I even searched for such option in exim configuration with no luck.

help i need this soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$message_body` by default contains no more than 500 initial bytes of message body.

https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/filter_ch-exim_filter_files.html#SEC19

> $message_body: The initial portion of the body of the message. By default, up to 500 characters are read into this variable, but the system administrator can configure this to some other value. Newlines in the body are converted into single spaces.